# Solidity - Error: identifier not found or unique

Tags: arrays, mapping, blockchain, solidity

I tried to compile this code and it gives me an error (identifier not found or not unique ) why ?? please help me!!
the concept of the code is adding an element in an array inside an array of struct and then search if an element exists to not
I used a compiler 0.4.0

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Ballot {
  struct EntityStruct {
    uint[] entityData;
    bool isEntity;
    bool iscontent;
    uint vote;
    uint predata;
    string isrep;
  }

    mapping(address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs;
    mapping(uint => entityData) public enitiyinfo;
    uint[] public datalist;
    address[] public entityList;

function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityDataa) public returns(uint rowNumber) {
   bytes32 datahash;
   uint counter = 0;
   datahash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(entityDataa));
   for (uint i=0; i<entityList.length; i++)
   {
       for (uint y=0; y<datalist.length; y++)
       {
           
       if (datahash == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(entityStructs[entityList[i]].entityData[datalist[y]])))
       {
       counter = counter+1;
       }
   }
   }
 //  if (counter >0)
  // {
   require(counter == 0,"not aloowed!!");
   entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData.push(entityDataa);
  // entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityDataa;
   entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = true;
   return entityList.push(entityAddress)-1;
   
   

}

function SearchForContent( uint data) public{
    uint rr = 0;
           for (uint i=0; i<entityList.length; i++) {
               for (uint y=0; y<5; y++)
               {
                   
               
               if ( data == entityStructs[entityList[i]].entityData[y])
               rr = rr+1;
           }
           require(rr >0,"not available data");
              // result = "available data";
               //else
            //require(data == entityStructs[entityList[i]].entityData,"notexsists data!!");
                          
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from line 13:

`mapping(uint => entityData) public enitiyinfo;`

Your `entityData` type is only defined in the scope of the `EntityStruct` struct: the rest of the program doesn't know what it is. However, it looks like you never actually use the mapping in question, so you can just remove that line.

Then your code compiles fine using v0.4.26. Some earlier 0.4.x versions do not support some of the features you use though, so you might want to reflect that in your `pragma` statement.

Comment: thanks for your information. how I can use the ```entityData``` ( the array of integers)  parameter of the struct inside the functions